# Is it possible to take an input in R?

Tags: r

New to programming and learning R after studying C++ for a few months. Is it possible to get user input like cin in C++. I want my program to take a Binary response from the user and increment or decrement depending if its true or false.

```
#Declaring the function
vector.maker.num1 <-function(len){
  #first condition results in the original function
  #used missing keyword to no get error message
  if(missing(len)){
    print(sample(1:20, 5))
  }
  #second condition results in printing a string warning of the length
  #being too small. Follewed by a random sample of any number below 5
  else if(len < 5){
    print("Warning Number is too small")
    sample(1:20, len)
  } 
  #same logic as previous condition except this one is for any number above
  #10 and it prints number being too large. Will still print the statement if it
  #is true but will not sample anything above 20.
  else if(len > 10){
    print("Number is too large")
    sample(1:20, len)
  }
#last condition of the function, executed if no other conditions are applicable
# only true if it is in between 5-10.
else{
    print("Number is just right")
    sample(1:20, len)
  }
}
vector.maker.num1(4)
```

Comment: To get interactive user input, see `help("readline")`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is: use the function `readline`

eg

```
name <- readline("What is your name? ")
```